How to preserve control position and sizing on an Excel Taskpane
I have an issue with a custom Excel taskpane.  The taskpane has been put together using the Winforms form designer.  The content of the form is correctly laid out in the designer (see attached), however at runtime all the control are squashed to the top of the taskpane (see attached):


What is  happening here?  I have not done anything to make the form behave in this manner.

When your Thread / Process is not DpiAware and it becomes part of one that is DpiAware (or references assemblies that are intrinsically DpiAware), it becomes itself DpiAware. Design your Project keeping DpiAwareness in mind (you can see the blurriness of the Form in the first image, that means the window has been virtualized) -- See the notes here: DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other -- In any case, you have to design your application for this, adjusting it after is never easy

With design your application for this, I mean you have to keep in mind that your windows (Forms and other Controls) will be scaled. Use nested containers to create the layout, use anchoring and docking wisely, possibly leveraging the capabilities of specialized container, as the FlowLayoutPanel and the TableLayoutPanel -- Test a lot, in different screen configurations

I've removed the visual-studio tag, it's not relevant. Add instead a tag that describes what .NET version you're targeting

You can set DPI awareness mode of your program by using Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode) Method, like this:
static void Main()
{
    Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}


Now, are you sure the OP is targeting .NET (Core) instead of .NET Framework? It looks like it's a standard VSTO Add-in project...

Just to confirm, the development is a straightforward VSTO, under .NET Framework 4.8
